# ReactJS onSubmit on form doesn't work

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, reactjs

I have a mystery trouble: when I clicking to the button or press enter, nothing is happen.

```
Row = ReactBootstrap.Row
Col = ReactBootstrap.Col
Input = ReactBootstrap.Input
Button = ReactBootstrap.Button

@NewSession = React.createClass
  handleSubmit: (e) ->
    alert 'f'
    e.preventDefault()
    Dispatcher.query('sessions', {}, 'POST')
  render: ->
    <form onSubmit={@handleSubmit} noValidate>
      <Row>
        <Col md={6} mdOffset={3} className='text-center'>
          <Input type='text' placeholder='Your username' ref='login' />
          <Input type='text' placeholder='Your password' ref='password' />
          <Button bsStyle='success'>Sign in</Button>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </form>
```

What is the reason of this strange behavior? Why handleSubmit doesn't work?

**UPDATED**

If I place `onClick={@handleSubmit}` handler on button, clicking is works

Comment: have you tried logging something in the `handleSubmit` function?

Comment: Yes, I've edited the question. Both `console.log` & 'alert' can't give me anything

Comment: try this `{this.handleSubmit}` instead of `{@handleSubmit}`. see if it helps.

Comment: Absolutely identical

Comment: strange. looks ok to me. any errors in `console` window?

Comment: Nope. I can't see anything

Comment: @knowbody what did you mean?

Comment: @asiniy ignore me, looking at it once again, sorry

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: Try this `onSubmit={() -> alert 'hello'}` and or are you preprocessing the jsx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

react-bootstrap `Button` components [default to `type="button"`](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/f26ba6aa69c367b5bd6423cb2bf288a35efb9849/src/Button.js#L84), so you need to add `type="submit"` to create a submit button.

```
<Button type='submit' bsStyle='success'>Sign in</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any submit event... You need to declare a type=submit inside the render method. Then you can use your onSubmit event handler function. Example below:

```html
   <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
  <div className="form-group col-sm-7">
          <input type="text" className="form-control" ref="inputmessage" id="inputDefault" />
  </div>
   <div className="form-group col-sm-5">
  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-block btn-primary">Send Message </button>
  </div>
  </form>
```